# Downloading an iOS app from a website, no App Store required

Tags: ios, app-store

Multiple websites offer the possibility of downloading app(s) directly from their site, without the use of the App Store ([emu4ios.net](https://emu4ios.net), [iemulators.com](http://iemulators.com), [gba4iosapp.com](http://www.gba4iosapp.com)).

By following the guidelines provided on these sites, the app will be downloaded and installed on my device.

My question is, how is this achieved, and how may I accomplish this with my own app/website?

Comment: enterprise account.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: @Idan What I don't get - so all of those apps that do stuff like tethering that apple removes from the store - all a developer would need to do is get am enterprise account and they could distribute it anyway to anyone they want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an enterprise certificate. And as soon as you do this, your certificate will be revoked. However if the user sets their day back before the certificate was revoked the app will install properly.

Please note, enterprise certificates are expensive, and its probably better you buy the normal developer package.

Comment: So what you're saying is - if Apple sees this, they'll revoke the certificate and people will no longer be able to install it?

Comment: Yes. But if the user sets the devices date to a day before the certificate was revoked, they will be able to install the app.